# How does this joke (?) of Gonff's work?

Tags: brian-jacques, redwall-series

There's a line by Gonff in *Mossflower* that's clearly supposed to be a joke, but I just... don't get it.

> Gonff was conscious of Columbine watching him. Bella had given the little mousethief permission to sing grace, and he stood up boldly and sang aloud,
>
> > Squirrels, otters, hedgehogs, mice,
> > Moles with fur like sable,
> > Gathered in good spirits all,
> > Round this festive table.
> > Sit we down to eat and drink.
> > Friends, before we do, let's think.
> > Fruit of forest, field and banks,
> > To the springtime we give thanks.
>
> The woodlanders began passing food. As Gonff sat down, he winked at Columbine, showing no sign of modesty.
> "Good, eh? **That's an ancient chant that has been sung through the ages. I composed it a moment ago for today**."
> Gonff was so pleased with himself that Columbine could not help laughing with him at his outrageous statement.
> <sub>Chapter 15</sub>

Of the two contradictory statements, "I composed it a moment ago for today" is probably the true one, as Gonff makes up a lot of other songs. However I don't see how including "That's an ancient chant that has been sung through the ages" makes a joke? It's obviously wrong, but somehow clever and hilarious, if I understand the Columbine's reaction correctly.

How does this joke (?) of Gonff's work?

<sub>I ask with full understanding that explaining jokes usually "ruins" them, but as I'm already confused it can't hurt more.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's just that the contradiction is a joke.  The "outrageous statement" is the whole thing - "This is an ancient chant, honestly, even though I've just made it up".

Along the lines of:

> One fine day in the middle of the night,
> Two dead men got up to fight.
> Back to back they faced each other,
> Drew their swords and shot each other.